# How to create dynamic responsive four columns with border style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a responsive four columns and I want to make it dynamic since i'll be creating this one for `custom_post` in **wordpress**. Here is my problem.

[image]

Since it's dynamic then the maximum column is 4 so I have this list of items I want to remove the `border-style` of the last element so I can make it using `:last-child` but my problem is that if the page is being resized then the columns will split into 3 , 2 , 1 and so on and also if I have just 1 or 2 or 3 items how can I target that items and have those borders in the middle and make it horizontally center. Do I need to do this with jquery or I can make it with pure CSS?

Check my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/leonardeveloper/cb162Lwv/5/)
**Note:** I can have as many item as possible.

Comment: I'd go with grid systems and `@media` queries to achieve that.

Comment: If by using media queries I will split the columns by 3, then it's nth-child is 3n, if 2 then 2n, and so on? Something like that?

Comment: select the first item to remove border then draw border from the left , nth-cild count will, anyhow, be necessary for each numbers of column  https://jsfiddle.net/cb162Lwv/6/ (why first ? because if it stands alone, it is as well the last ... dilemma, wich style overrides wich :)

Comment: @GCyrillus awesome! Maybe you can post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will certainly need @media queries for the borders.

To center the items you could use

```
#spring-vet-inner {
    text-align: center;
}

#spring-vet-inner .sv-list {
    display: inline-block;
    width:50%;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:40px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/stby04/m1x78tL2/

Answer (score 1):

from my earlier comment:

---

If you select the first item to remove border then draw border from the left it might be easier to sort .

```css
/* parent , here body */
body {
    text-align:center;
  }
#spring-vet-inner .sv-list {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:49%;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:40px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
@media (min-width:768px) {
    #spring-vet-inner .sv-list {
        width:24%;
        min-height:250px;
        border-left:solid 1px #002320
    }
    #spring-vet-inner .sv-list:nth-child(4n-2) {
        border-left-color:red;
    }
    #spring-vet-inner .sv-list:nth-child(4n+1) {
        border-left:0 none;
        clear:both;
    }
}
#spring-vet-inner .sv-list:first-of-type {
    border-left:none;
}
#spring-vet-inner .sv-list p {
    font-family:"RalewaySemiBold";
    font-size:16px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    padding-top:18px;
}
#spring-vet-inner .sv-list h1 {
    font-family:"NeutraTextDemiAlt";
    font-size:18px;
    margin-bottom:42px;
    font-weight:normal;
}
#spring-vet-inner .sv-list h1 span {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="spring-vet-inner">

  <div class="sv-list">
    <p>FELINE DENTISTRY</p>
    <h1>ORLANDO <span>APRIL 11 & 12</span> 2015</h1><a class="btn-learn" href=
    "#">LEARN MORE</a>
  </div>

  <div class="sv-list">
    <p>CANINE DENTISTRY</p>
    <h1>ORLANDO <span>MARCH 14 & 15</span> 2015</h1><a class="btn-learn" href=
    "#">LEARN MORE</a>
  </div>

  <div class="sv-list">
    <p>FELINE DENTISTRY</p>
    <h1>ORLANDO <span>APRIL 11 & 12</span> 2015</h1><a class="btn-learn" href=
    "#">LEARN MORE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="sv-list">
    <p>CANINE DENTISTRY</p>
    <h1>ORLANDO <span>MARCH 14 & 15</span> 2015</h1><a class="btn-learn" href=
    "#">LEARN MORE</a>
  </div>

  <div class="sv-list">
    <p>FELINE DENTISTRY</p>
    <h1>ORLANDO <span>APRIL 11 & 12</span> 2015</h1><a class="btn-learn" href=
    "#">LEARN MORE</a>
  </div>

  <div class="sv-list">
    <p>CANINE DENTISTRY</p>
    <h1>ORLANDO <span>MARCH 14 & 15</span> 2015</h1><a class="btn-learn" href=
    "#">LEARN MORE</a>
  </div>

  <div class="sv-list">
    <p>FELINE DENTISTRY</p>
    <h1>ORLANDO <span>APRIL 11 & 12</span> 2015</h1><a class="btn-learn" href=
    "#">LEARN MORE</a>
  </div>
      <div class="sv-list">
    <p>CANINE DENTISTRY</p>
    <h1>ORLANDO <span>MARCH 14 & 15</span> 2015</h1><a class="btn-learn" href=
    "#">LEARN MORE</a>
  </div>

  <div class="sv-list">
    <p>FELINE DENTISTRY</p>
    <h1>ORLANDO <span>APRIL 11 & 12</span> 2015</h1><a class="btn-learn" href=
    "#">LEARN MORE</a>
  </div>

  <div class="sv-list">
    <p>CANINE DENTISTRY</p>
    <h1>ORLANDO <span>MARCH 14 & 15</span> 2015</h1><a class="btn-learn" href=
    "#">LEARN MORE</a>
  </div>

  <div class="sv-list">
    <p>FELINE DENTISTRY</p>
    <h1>ORLANDO <span>APRIL 11 & 12</span> 2015</h1><a class="btn-learn" href=
    "#">LEARN MORE</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

`nth-child` count will, anyhow, be necessary for each numbers of column ,(to tune from `first-of-type`/`:first-child`)

why choose first ? 
because if it stands alone, it is as well the last ... dilemma, wich style overrides wich :)

Comment: And also how can I center the items? or the last few elements if it's 1, 2, 3?

Comment: @LeonardDrapeza i just updated the snippet. for this you need to drop the **floa**t and use **display:inline-block** or **inline-table;**  **text-align:center;** on parent will do the job then.

Answer (score 0):

Like what has been mentioned above you will need to set the breaking point for each of the sizes based on the screen width you want. For example using your JS.Fiddle if you add this CSS code:

```
@media (max-width:767px){
    #spring-vet-inner .sv-list:nth-child(odd) {
        border-right: 1px solid red;
    }
}
```

The border shows up correctly for your 2 column layout once the page container is shrunk down. You can see your [updated JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/cb162Lwv/7/). This should get you started. Hope that helps.